# How to rotate the text labels for the x Axis of a nvd3.js line chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am new to nvd3 and d3 js.I am creating a line chart using nvd3. Now i want to rotate the text labels for the x Axis of the line chart.How to implement this?
I tried using

```
var xTicks = d3.selectAll('g.tick');
   xTicks
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('transform', function(d,i,j) { return ' rotate(-90 0,0)' }) ;
```

but was unsuccessful

My current code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="../build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../build/nv.d3.js"></script>

    <style>
        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
        }
        html, body, #chart1, svg {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .dashed {
            stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
        }
    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    function download()
    {


img = new Image(),
        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
        svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg'));

    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);

    // You could also use the actual string without base64 encoding it:
    //img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + svgStr;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    var w=3000;
    var h=3000;

    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);

    var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
    dlLink.download = "image";
    dlLink.href = imgURL;
    dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = ["image/png", dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

    document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
    dlLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(dlLink);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
<div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <button onclick="randomizeFillOpacity();">Randomize fill opacity</button>
    <button onclick="expandLegend();">Expand/Contract Legend</button>
    <script>
        var expandLegend = function() {
            var exp = chart.legend.expanded();
            chart.legend.expanded(!exp);
            chart.update();
        }
    </script>
</div>
<div id="chart1" width="100%" height='100%'></div>
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>

<script>
    // Wrapping in nv.addGraph allows for '0 timeout render', stores rendered charts in nv.graphs, and may do more in the future... it's NOT required
    var chart;
    var data;

    var randomizeFillOpacity = function() {
        var rand = Math.random(0,1);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // modify sine amplitude
            data[4].values[i].y = Math.sin(i/(5 + rand)) * .4 * rand - .25;
        }
        data[4].fillOpacity = rand;
        chart.update();
    };

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .options({
                transitionDuration: 300,
                useInteractiveGuideline: true
            })
        ;

        // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel("Time (s)")

            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'))
            .staggerLabels(true)

           ;


        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                if (d == null) {
                    return 'N/A';
                }
                return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
            })
        ;

        data = sinAndCos();

        d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
            .datum(data)
            .attr("id","svg")
            .attr("height","1000")
            .attr("width","1000")
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });

    function sinAndCos() {
        var /*sin = [],
            sin2 = [],*/
            cos = [],
           /* rand = [],*/
            rand2 = []
            ;

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});

            rand2.push({x: i, y: Math.cos(i/10) + Math.random() / 10 })
        }

        return [
            {
                values: cos,
                key: "Cosine Wave",
                color: "#2ca02c"
            },
            {
                values: rand2,
                key: "Random Cosine",
                color: "#667711",
                strokeWidth: 3.5,
                fillOpacity: .1,
                classed: 'dashed',
                 area: true,
            }
        ];
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
chart.xAxis
    .rotateLabels(-45)
```